# ¿Es posible crear un nuevo calendario de Google desde una App en Android?

Tags: android, api, android-intent, google-calendar, calendar

Quiero crear un calendario de Google mediante programación que se sincronice con la cuenta de Google.

He estado buscando y mediante `ContentProvider` te permite crear calendarios locales con el tipo `ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL` que no permiten la sincronización. He leído que mediante `SyncAdapters` se puede hacer pero la información que he encontrado es muy vaga y no me ha aclarado nada.

Si alguien conoce la forma de realizar esto y puede darme unas pautas a seguir o algún ejemplo estaré agradecido.